# How to convert a boolean formula to CNF or DNF

Tags: c#, discrete-mathematics

Say I have a boolean formula
 a or (b and c)

I would wish to convert it to CNF
i.e. 
(a and b) or (a and c)

Is there any existing library that could achieve this?

Comment: I'm assuming then your "formula" is in some form that's not your standard C# `if (a || (b && c))` condition?

Comment: How do you represent the formula (by a string lets say?)

Comment: I am thinking that if there is a library that support this, would should a way to encode the formula..like
lib.or(a,lib.and(b,c))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement it yourself, here is an example of how to play with Linq Expressions formulas. The [sample program](http://blogs.southworks.net/dgeffner/2011/09/26/implementing-complex-case-analysis/) derivates and simplifies formulas, which isn't exactly what you want to do, but is near enough to be useful.

P.S..: If I remember my logic correctly, there are multiple ways to express the same formula in either CNF or DNF given a starting formula. You might want to normalize it someway, to get something that it's always consistent.